# Jumping on meshes in Babylon.js

Tags: mathematics, javascript

So I want to make it possible for players to jump on objects (meshes) that are somewhat lower than the players camera.

I have set the checkCollisions to true but i can't seem to jump on any objects

(I'm using Babylon.js)

Here is my jump function

```
//Object i wanna jump on
var cube = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box", 10, scene);
cube.checkCollisions = true;
cube.position.y = - 4.5 ;


//Jump function
_playerJump : function(){
        $this = this;

        if($this.isJumping == false && $this.energy - 30 >= 0){
            var
                camera = $this.camera,      
                jumpAnim = new BABYLON.Animation("jumpAnim", "position.y", 20, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_FLOAT, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CYCLE),
                keys = [],
                jumpStep;

            camera.animations = [];

            for(jumpStep = 0; jumpStep < 23; jumpStep ++)
                keys.push({frame: jumpStep, value: camera.position.y + jumpStep / 5});

            for(jumpStep = 24; jumpStep < 46; jumpStep ++)
                keys.push({frame: jumpStep, value: camera.position.y + 4.8 - (jumpStep - 24) / 5});



            jumpAnim.setKeys(keys);

            var easingFunction = new BABYLON.BezierCurveEase(.13,.01,.63,1.41);
            easingFunction.setEasingMode(BABYLON.EasingFunction.EASINGMODE_EASEIN);
            jumpAnim.setEasingFunction(easingFunction);

            camera.animations.push(jumpAnim);

            $this.isJumping = true;

            $this._setEnergy(-30);

            $this.scene.beginAnimation(camera, 0, 46, false, 4, function(){
                $this.isJumping = false;
                $this.isCrouching = false;
            });
        }
    }
```